# Is it is possible to disable the loading bar in zkoss?

Tags: zk

Is there any way to disable the loading bar in zkoss framework?

Answer (score 4):

well... im not sure about what kind of loading message you want to disable

there're two kinds of busy, one is on left top, another is on center with full page mask.

i create a button to test them

```
<zk>
<button label="showMaskBusy" onClick='Clients.showBusy("some message...")' />
<button label="showLeftTopBusy" onClick='org.zkoss.lang.Threads.sleep(10000)' />
</zk>
```

then the way to disable them is using CSS

```
 /**Center + Mask Busy**/

 #zk_showBusy {
   display: none !important;
 }

 /**Left Top Busy**/
 .z-loading-indicator { 
   display: none !important;
 }
```

try add them into the test button page.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about the loading message? If not please let me know.

You can do this by setting the style to display: none; in the CSS. You can do this by following the [Style Guide entry](http://books.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Style_Guide/Miscellaneous/Loading).